# Images are not displaying in asp.net webforms

Tags: sql, asp.net, repeater

I have image links of a website's images stored in my DB but when I show them on my asp page using repeater or data list which im building, it shows some where pics and somewhere just boxes and no
 image, can anyone help me?
here is my datalist code to show products but some images are being shown and some are like broken icons and empty box having no image, and i have image links of a website which i am displaying in
 data list and i have checked all links as well on web they work perfectly fine but don't show anything in my data list web form,is this a styling issue or binding?
 code of Data list is given below

```
 <div style=" border:inset; margin-left:100px; display:inline-block;">
                  <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <ItemTemplate>     
                            <div class="span4" style="display:inline-block; border-top:1px; background-color:none;width:190px; height:440px;  border:solid; border-width:1px; border-spacing:2px 4px; border-bottom:inset; border-top-width:1px;" runat="server"><br />  

                                  <div class="products" style="height:430px; width:189x; border:inset;border-style:none;border-spacing:2px 4px;"> 

                                      <asp:Image ID="ImgId" runat="server" style=" height:160px; width:160px;" ImageUrl='<%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImageLink")) %>' /> <br />

                                    <h3 class="title" style="font-family:Pristina;font-size:medium;height:30px; margin-bottom:-15px;"> <b><%# Eval("Name") %></b><br /><br /><br /></h3>
                                      <br />        
                                    <p class="price" style="font-family:Pristina;font-size:medium; height:30px;padding-top:40px; "><b>Price</b> <%# Eval("Price") %> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p><br />
                                      <br />
                                    <a href="<%#Eval("Link") %>" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Malgun Gothic';font-size:medium;"><b style="margin-bottom:-20px">www.shophive.com</b></a>

                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                             </ItemTemplate> 
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                        </asp:DataList>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: Attention to your image URLs. Absolute and relative path in any place that you have images.Test image URLs in your browser.

Comment: @BKO this is what i have tried some images displays and some just empty box and a broken little icon? it's image binding thingy or what?

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited i have checked all the URLs in the browser they work fine, but in data list on web form some images are displaying and others are just empty boxes, what should i do?

Comment: I feel something is wrong about your tests.

Comment: you have already asked and yeah it can be a problem of hotlinking as someone said to you,